# How to use Protractor Locator for web testing JQWidget

Tags: testing, web, protractor, jqwidget

Hi I'm new to using ProTractor. I followed the tutorial on their website and I think I understand it pretty well.

The website I need to test is a bit confusing. It has a JQwidget table on some of the pages. The column headers have two parts: one is a text part that when you click on it, it just rotates thru all the orders; the second one is an icon that when you click it there's a dropdown menu to select asc/desc order.

I used inspect element on the column header in browser, below is what gets highlighted: 
[image]

It seems like the icon part has an ID so I can just use by.ID(), but the text part doesn't. If I just want to click the text part how do I do that?

Also wondering what is the best way of finding attributes/locators to use for testing wed stuff?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Give some code example based on the [jQuery Table demo](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/customsorting.htm):

Some basic functions for further function to operate column header:

```
var utils = require('util');

findColumnHeader(columnName) {
    // find column by column text
    return element(by.xpath(
                util.format("//div[@role='columnheader'][.='%s']", columnName)
            ));
}

mouseOverColumnHeader(columnHeader) {
    // mouseover on column header
    return browser.executeScript('$(argument[0]).mouseover()',
           columnHeader.getWebElement());
}

makeSortMenuDisplay(columnName) {
    var columnHeader = findColumnHeader(columnName);

    // mouse over on the column header 
    mouseOverColumnHeader(columnHeader)

    .then(function() {
        // click on the icon to display sort menu
        columnHeader.element(by.css('div.iconscontainer + div')).click();
    });
}
```

[image]

Below functions to operate the column header use above basic functions:

```
clickColumnHeader(columnName) {
    // click on the column header
    return findColumnHeader(columnName).click();
}

clickAscSort(columnName) {      
    return makeSortMenuDisplay(columnName)

    .then(function()) {
        // click on the ASC sort menu
        element(by.css('div.jqx-menu-wrapper li > div.jqx-grid-sortasc-icon')).click();
    }
}

clickDescSort(columnName) {
    return makeSortMenuDisplay(columnName)

    .then(function()) {
        // click on the DeSC sort menu
        element(by.css('div.jqx-menu-wrapper li > div.jqx-grid-sortdesc-icon')).click();
    }
}

clickRemoveSort(columnName) {
    return makeSortMenuDisplay(columnName)

    .then(function()) {
        // click on the DeSC sort menu
        element(by.css('div.jqx-menu-wrapper li > div.jqx-grid-sortremoev-icon')).click();
    }
}
```

More practice on css selector and xpath, then you will good at to write locator.